# Alpha Animation for each List Row

Tags: android, xml, animation, alpha

I want to set a background drawable to 1st element of list view, also to other elements of the list view I want to set the same drawable but it should be little faded. I dont want to use two images for this.

I tried using Alpha Animation for this:
In getView of my List View i used This:

```
            Animation animation  = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.alpha_anim);

            if (position == 0) {

                list_row_layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_image);

            } else {
                list_row_layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_image);


                animation.setDuration(0);
                animation.setFillAfter( true );



                if (list_row_layout != null){

                    list_row_layout.startAnimation(animation);
                } 

            }
```

and here is my alpha_anim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromAlpha="0.0"
android:toAlpha="0.5"
android:duration="1000" />
```

The problem is it is working fine, but the animation gets applied to 0th element also.
I tried cancelling the animation if(position == 0) but its not working.

I need to know can we apply Alpha animation to each ListRow element separately?

Comment: Did yu worked with **listView.setLayoutAnimation()**???

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [ListViewAnimation](https://github.com/Grishu/Animated_Listview) which contains the [AlphaAnimation](https://github.com/Grishu/Animated_Listview/blob/master/ListViewwithAnimation/src/com/grishu/listviewanimations/appearanceexamples/AppearanceExamplesActivity.java) for the list of items in ListView.

User `AlphaAnimation` class as below to apply alpha effects on your `ListView`

```
  private void setAlphaAdapter() {
    AnimationAdapter animAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(mAdapter);
    animAdapter.setAbsListView(getListView());
    getListView().setAdapter(animAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why animate it? Have you tried [setAlpha](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29) ?

Oh, and about the first element, add setAlpha(1f) for pos == 0. I think it might have something to do with reusing the listelements...

Comment: That requires API level 11 and above, I am supporting API 9

Comment: mh ok, well try to add an animation to 100% oppacity for the element at pos == 0 then. Maybe that helps

Comment: use this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LayoutAnimationController.html